# ways to calculate norm of the Bounded Linear Functional.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

$\Lambda$ be a linear functional on $C([0,1])$ defined by
$$
\Lambda(f) = \int_0^1 xf(x)dx \;\;\; \text{ for } f \in C([0,1]).
$$
and use $\|f\|_{sup} = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| $ for $f \in C([0,1])$.

I'm trying to find all $f \in C([0,1])$ with $\|\Lambda (f) \| = \|\Lambda\| \|f\|$.

I already solve a similar problem about the norm of bounded linear functional, but I still don't know how to calculate the norm in general case. Is there any way to calculate norm of bounded linear functional?

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: @KBS I only show that $|\Lambda(f)| \leq \|f \|_{sup}$

Comment: Try to find an upper bound on $|\Lambda(f)|$ when $||f||=1$ using standard inequalities.

Comment: @KBS Do you mean $|  \Lambda f | \leq \int_0^1 |xf(x)|dx \leq \|f\|_{sup}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for every $f\in C[0,1]$ we have  $|\Lambda f|\leq\frac{1}{2}\|f\|$,
and there is equality if $f$ is the constant function $1$, the norm of $\Lambda$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.
Let $f\in C[0,1]$ be such that $\|f\|=1$, and such that $\Lambda f=\frac{1}{2}$. Put $$A=\{x\in [0,1]| f(x)\geq 0 \}$$
Then
$$\frac{1}{2}=\int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx=\int_A xf(x)\,dx + \int_{[0,1]\backslash A}xf(x)\,dx\leq \int_A xf(x)\,dx\leq \frac{1}{2}$$
Hence $f$ must be non-negative almost everywhere, and since it is continuous, it must be non-negative everywhere. Now, if there is a certain value of $0\leq x\leq 1$ for which $0\leq f(x)<1$, then by continuity there is some interval where $0\leq f(x)<1$, and so
$$\int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx < \int_0^1x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}$$
Conclusion: the only norm-$1$ continuous function for which $\Lambda f=\frac{1}{2}$ is the constant function $1$. As a result, the functions satisfying $\|\Lambda f\|=\|\Lambda\|\|f\|$ are precisely the constant functions, and this is the answer to your question.

Comment: I think I understand your answer, but I have a question for checking my understanding. So $f$ has to be constant function to satisfies equity? If I restrict the function space $C([0,1])$ to $\{f \in C([0,1] : f(1) = a \}, a \in C([0,1])$ for example, $f$ has to be $f = a$. Right?

Comment: I mean, $a \in [0,1]$ like $a=0$.

Comment: The set you mentioned is indeed a subspace only if $a=0$. In that case, your functional will not attain its norm on that particular subspace. The norm will still be $1/2$, because you can find continuous functions satisfying $f(0)=1$ whose norm is $1$ in $C[0,1]$, but you cannot find a continuous function satisfying $f(0)=1$ for which there will be inequality. Keep in mind that functionals do not always attain their norm.

Comment: Did you mean that $f(1)=0$?

Comment: yes, I meant $f(1)=0$, but it doesn't matter much; you could just as well looked at a subspace for which $f(0)=0$, or for that matter $f(c)=0$ for any $0\leq c\leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**General case**. Any linear bounded functional $A \colon C([0,1]) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ can be represented in the form of Riemann–Stieltjes integral
$$
A(f) = \int\limits_0^1 f(x) dg(x),
$$
where $g$ is a function of bounded variation. Furthermore $\lVert A \rVert = \mathop{\mathrm{Var}}_0^1[g]$.

**Your particular case**. Let $g(t) = \dfrac{t^2}{2}$ and $\mu_g$ is Lebesgue–Stieltjes measure defined by the function $g$. We can represent $\Lambda$ in the form of Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral: $\Lambda(f) = \int\limits_0^1 x f(x)dx = \int\limits_0^1 f(x) d \mu_g$. Then $\lVert \Lambda \rVert = \mathop{\mathrm{Var}}_0^1[g] = \Big[g \in C^1([0,1])\Big] = \int\limits_{0}^{1} |g'(t)| dt = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The OP could have found out by themself with some help. Please refrain providing full answers to exercises in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $f\equiv 0$ is a solution. So let's assume $f$ is not identically $0$.

The operator norm is given by $\|\Lambda\|=\sup_{\|g\|=1}\|\Lambda(g)\|$. So your equation becomes
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\|\Lambda(f)\|}{\|f\|}=\sup_{\|g\|=1}\|\Lambda(g)\|.
\end{equation*}

Note that the LHS can be rewritten, due to linearity, as $\|\Lambda(\frac{f}{\|f\|})\|$. So the LHS is always less or equal than the RHS, with equality if and only if $\|\Lambda(g)\|=\|\Lambda\|$, where $g:=\frac{f}{\|f\|}$.

That means that if $f$ satisfies your equation, $f$ normalized is the maximizer in the computation of the norm of $\Lambda$. Now clearly, $\|\Lambda\|\leq \frac{1}{2}$ since $xf(x)\leq x\|f(x)\|\leq x$ whenever $\|f\|=1$ and taking $f\equiv 1$, we can see that $\|\Lambda(f)\|=\frac{1}{2}$, so $\|\Lambda\|=\frac{1}{2}$.

So now the question simply becomes what are $f\in C([0,1])$ with $\|f\|=1$ such that $\int_0^1 xf(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. Then all your solutions will be $\lambda f$ for arbitrary constants $\lambda$. Argue that this means $f\equiv\lambda$ using the continuity of $f$.

Comment: The OP could have found out by themself with some help. Please refrain providing full answers to exercises in the future.